# Simple jquery slideshow causing High CPU Usage

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cpu

So I decided to use a simple 1-line jquery content slider instead of opting for bloated plugins. I'm using [animated.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) for text fade ins apart from the jquery for fading in/out slides.

HTML:

```
<section id="student-blocks">
    <div>
        <h2 class="animated fadeUp">News Item #1</h2>
        <p "animated fadeIn">lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2 class="animated fadeUp">News Item #2</h2>
        <p "animated fadeIn">lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2 class="animated fadeUp">News Item #3</h2>
        <p "animated fadeIn">lorem</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function ()
{

    $("#student-blocks > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function ()
    {
        $('#student-blocks > div:first')
        .hide()
        .next()
        .fadeIn()
        .end()
        .appendTo('#student-blocks');
    }, 4000);
});
```

***PAGE IS HOSTED HERE: http://cloud69.comoj.com/pages/***

**The Problem**

This slideshow causes my CPU usage to shoot up to 15% to 20%. I tried collecting a CPU profile, and saw spikes at regular time intervals (maybe when slides are changing).

Why is the CPU usage so high?  How do I make it better?

Comment: I would choose the `.appendTo()` as the culprit here.

Comment: Try to use `.html()` instead and see if it helps.

Comment: Another change would be to _cache_ the selector into a variable, so you don't need to select it everytime: `var myItem = $('#student-blocks')` and `var myFirstItem = $('#student-blocks > div:first')`. Something around these lines.

Comment: Does my solution only with css helps you and solve yout problems? take a look below plz

Comment: Try chrome profiler to see what jQuery exactly is causing the memory leak,what is that?

Comment: Is that all the code there is involved or a slim down version? The code posted in the answer makes my CPU go to 0.1% and it's doing what the code you posted do. Is there images involved maybe which would affect the CPU with rendering time?

Comment: Also you seems to be missing the attribute in `<p "animated fadeIn">` on your posted example.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly at your question I'm doubtful you will get any meaningful improvements by optimizing the code posted (20 -25% you said is a very hign number!).BUT let's see what we can do.So,at your code, you use  `$('#student-blocks > div:first')` outside the interval function like:

`var el $('#student-blocks > div:first');` , and use the `el` element variable.
**Much better** is to use this selector:

```
var el = $("#student-blocks").find("div:first");
```

**ALSO, the best for **performance** selector ** according to this [article](http://jamesallardice.com/selecting-the-first-element-with-jquery/)  would be:

`$("#student-blocks div:first-of-type");`

In conclusion, I would change the code as follows: [(http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/104cuxxb/)](http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/104cuxxb/)

```js
var studentsblocks = $("#student-blocks");
var el = studentsblocks.find("div:first-of-type");
$(studentsblocks).find("div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function ()
{
    el
    .hide()
    .next()
    .fadeIn()
    .end()
    .appendTo(studentsblocks);
}, 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="student-blocks">
  <div>
    <h2 class="animated fadeUp">News Item #1</h2>
    <p "animated fadeIn">lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="animated fadeUp">News Item #2</h2>
    <p "animated fadeIn">lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="animated fadeUp">News Item #3</h2>
    <p "animated fadeIn">lorem</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Another approach would be to lower frame rate of your animation, or make changes that help the browsers rendering engine (which might be stuff like changing styles or the dom).

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION WITHOUT ANY PU PROBLEM USING ONLY CSS**

To make it better, I would use **only a simple CSS** . 
I made a fade-ffect for your example:
http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/104cuxxb/

CSS Only Implementation:

```css
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000;
  filter: dropshadow(color=#000000, offx=1, offy=1);
}
a:hover {
  color: #0097bc;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}
.slogan {
  width: 500px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #222;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .2);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .2);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 350ms;
  -moz-transition: background-color 350ms;
  transition: background-color 350ms;
}
.slogan span {
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  display: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #cccccc;
}
.slogan p {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000000;
  filter: dropshadow(color=#000000, offx=1, offy=1);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}
.slogan p:nth-child(1) {
  animation: left-one 20s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: left-one 20s ease infinite;
  -webkit-animation: left-one 20s ease infinite;
}
.slogan p:nth-child(2) {
  animation: left-two 20s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: left-two 20s ease infinite;
  -webkit-animation: left-two 20s ease infinite;
}
.slogan.down p {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
}
.slogan.down p:nth-child(1) {
  animation: down-one 20s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: down-one 20s ease infinite;
  -webkit-animation: down-one 20s ease infinite;
}
.slogan.down p:nth-child(2) {
  animation: down-two 20s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: down-two 20s ease infinite;
  -webkit-animation: down-two 20s ease infinite;
}
/*================================
 Move the slogan Downwards
==================================*/

/** Mozilla Firefox Keyframes **/

@-moz-keyframes down-one {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  10% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes down-two {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  90% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}
/** Webkit Keyframes **/

@-webkit-keyframes down-one {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  10% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes down-two {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h3>Cool fading text only with css .slogan down class</h3>
  <div class="slogan down">
    <p>News Item #1<span>lorem</span>
    </p>
    <p>News Item #2<span>lorem</span>
    </p>
    <p>News Item #3<span>lorem</span>
    </p>
    <p>News Item #4<span>lorem</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope you like it and that realy helps!

Comment: This looks nice and it's a good idea to use just CSS whenever possible, but it's not an answer to the question. If anyone else has a processor consuming script and look for an answer, could ends up here and maybe a CSS solution isn't the case.

Comment: i suggested an alternative way to the problem which is a solution since there are no cpu problems i think

Comment: You could first ask the OP in the comments if a CSS only solution would fit their requirements. If so, then it would be OK.

Comment: hm, i cant catch you but i admit that firstly i have to anser why is the cpu problem.Let me try this.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @MelanciaUK tell me your opinion now if you want.thanks.

Comment: I would query and cache `#student-blocks` and then query from that. it also means the variable can be use in the `appendTo` instead of a selector which would trigger a query on each interval.

Comment: I appreciate your solution! But the jquery optimsation didnt help at all! Your css - only solution is great, but device support for css animations here is a major concern!

Comment: @gillesc can you help me to improve this answer?

Comment: To be honest I wonder if the issue is with that code, my CPU usage when trying your jsfiddle is 0.1%

Comment: After query wise to improve I would do this. `var parent = document.getElementById("student-blocks"); var el = $("div:eq(0)", parent);` and then later `appendTo(parent);`. Only `el` needs to be a jQuery instance and we removed the last query inside the interval function. Query perf wise I haven't tested but it feels `$("div:eq(0)", parent)` would be better as no type check and contextual search. But `$(parent.getElementsByTagName("div")[0])` should be even faster.

Comment: @user3210476 check the solution again I updated,and the new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/104cuxxb/ .I think i s the best i can do. whats your opinion?

Comment: @gillesc I think yours is very good but maybe this http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/104cuxxb/ is better since jquery uses the user.

Comment: @user3210476 tell us which one helps .gillesc made a suggestion.

Comment: Okay, apparently the continuous HIGH CPu usage was due to a simple css keyframe animation (which I totally didnt expect!). After disabling those, I still get short spikes of 40% CPU at regular intervals. Also, I've hosted the page @ http://cloud69.comoj.com/pages/

Comment: @gillesc could you please post your solution as an answer?

Comment: @user3210476 did you try my last approach .see updated answer.I think is much better. and rea the article i mentioned in the answer. Gillesc made a solution with pure javascript.Is that you want? Whatever. is your choice :)